# WSL Gui Display not showing anything

Tags: linux, cmd, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, xserver

I am using a xserver (xlaunch) and have initalized it with

> export DISPLAY=$(grep nameserver /etc/resolv.conf | awk '{print $2}'):0.0

> export DISPLAY=$(route.exe print | grep 0.0.0.0 | head -1 | awk '{print $4}'):0.0

When i try to open xeyes everything happens as if it should be opening. However nothing opens.

Comment: Hi! Have you managed to solve this problem? Facing same issue...

Comment: No I have not :(

Comment: @Max_Meadowcroft Did you wait a little longer? Had the same. A minute later it timeouts with "Error: Can't open display:" and there is plenty of these questions around. Also didn't manage to fix it on my own.